# How to mock response from Capybara/Poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I have the scraping script using Ruby, Capybara and Poltergeist. The code works properly now I want to add rspec for my code. How can I stub the response when the code clicks the specific button and goes to the different page?

Here is my sample code

```
Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:js_errors => false, :timeout => 1000 })
Capybara.default_selector = :xpath
session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
session.driver.headers = { 'User-Agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X)" }

session.visit "https://sample.url"

# set ID
id = session.find("//input[@name='identifier']")
id.native.send_key('id')

# set password
password = session.find("//input[@name='password']")
password.native.send_key('pass')

# login
submit = session.find("//input[@value='submit']")
submit.trigger('click')

html = session.html

# Then parse html
```

Basically I want to stub `html` in rspec but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - you don't

Longer answer - Capybara is designed for writing feature tests, which are end-to-end tests of your app, during which you shouldn't be mocking/stubbing any of your app.  Additionally what would be the point of doing the interactions with the page if you then stubbed the response, since the interactions would be pointless? (You also generally shouldn't be calling `.native` or `.trigger` on anything in tests where you actually care about the site working).

It sounds like maybe you want to be writing a request spec or view spec instead (which don't use Capybara to interact with the page).

On a side note, if/when you are using Capybara with xpath (your current selectors would actually be better as CSS) you need to be aware of the `//` vs `.//` trap and default to using `.//` 99.99% of the time - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap